# How to Trigger a Page(Not Redirect) With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page and when a client use this page,
Javascript code trigger Another Page.
I dont want to redirect another page.
Javascript must only trigger another page and First page continue to its working.

this is imposible?

Comment: What does "trigger another page" mean?

Comment: Do you mean sending a request to another page without using the result of it? And is this page on the same domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the no-jQuery solution

```
var xhr = ("XMLHttpRequest" in window) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP");
xhr.open("GET", "pathtofile.html", true);
xhr.send("");
```

This will request a file from the server without doing anything to the response.

Answer (score 3):

It is called AJAX.

You should use a library like jQuery: 
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Why *should* he use a library for something so trivial?

Comment: Thanks,
But I dont want to JQuery.